# Object.prototype.toString.call is not working in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I need to check the type of my object in my NodeJS application. I tried to reuse the code I used in pure javascript for this.

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(jsone.cars) == '[object Array]'
```

But this is not working in NodeJS. What is the reason for this behavior? How can I do this in NodeJS?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is an error message displayed? The code excerpt included in the question has a syntax error (extraneous closing bracket)

Comment: no error message. I corrected the syntax error in the question

Comment: @Malintha So you expect true but this is giving you false right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working as expected.

```js
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call([]) == '[object Array]');
```

[image]

NodeJS: V8.11.3

**Please double check** your `jsone.cars` not return `undefined`.

Hope this may help you.